# Magento 2 command line utility saying "Access denied for user"

Tags: magento2

My magento 2 installation is working fine, but when I go to terminal and try to use any command, for example image resize, it is giving me following

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

As noted, front end is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are on localhost or on live server.

Using password:NO means you are trying to connect to mysql without password, so unless your database doesn't have a password,

Or you didn't updated your password field in **`env.php`**

In Magento 2.0, the configuration is in the same directory (`app/etc/`) and the file is **`env.php`**. The file path is:

```
app/etc/env.php
```

In this file, a number of key things are set, including the database connection information:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
'dbname' => 'magento2database',
'username' => 'some-username',
'password' => 'some password here',
```

Comment: This is normally the cause - however this is happening to me with the correct details in env.php.